# Multiple Foreign Keys EF Core 2.1 code first generates only 1 in DB

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.1, .net-core-2.1

I have the following model:

```cs
public class User : AuditedModel
{
    public string Login { get; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; }

    public User(string login, string password, User creationUser) : base(creationUser)
    {
        Login = login;
        PasswordHash = GeneratePasswordHash(password);
    }

    protected User(int id, DateTime creationDate, DateTime? terminationDate, string login, string passwordHash) : base(id, 0, creationDate)
    {
        Login = login;
        PasswordHash = passwordHash;
    }
}
public class AuditedModel : BaseModel
{
    protected AuditedModel(User creationUser)
    {
        CreationUser = creationUser;
        CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    public User CreationUser { get; protected set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; }
    public User TerminationUser { get; protected set; }
    public DateTime? TerminationDate { get; }
}
public class BaseModel
{
    public int Id { get;}

    protected BaseModel()
    {
    }

    public BaseModel(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

EF Core Code First should create two self-referencing foreing keys for `CreationUser` and `TerminationUser`, as specified in the Fluent API:

```cs
public class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(User));

        builder.HasKey(u => u.Id);
        builder.Property(u => u.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        builder.Property(u => u.Login)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(u => u.PasswordHash);

        builder.Property(u => u.CreationDate);

        builder.Property(u => u.TerminationDate);

        builder.HasOne(u => u.TerminationUser)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<User>(u => u.Id)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        builder.HasOne(u => u.CreationUser)
            .WithOne()
            .IsRequired()
            .HasForeignKey<User>(u => u.Id)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
     }
}
```

I intend to use migrations for this project, so I'm going to show the migration output, which reflects on the database:

```cs
public partial class InitialCreate : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.EnsureSchema(
            name: "public");

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "User",
            schema: "public",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.SerialColumn),
                CreationDate = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                TerminationUserId = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
                TerminationDate = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: true),
                Login = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                PasswordHash = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_User", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_User_User_TerminationUserId",
                    column: x => x.TerminationUserId,
                    principalSchema: "public",
                    principalTable: "User",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_User_TerminationUserId",
            schema: "public",
            table: "User",
            column: "TerminationUserId");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "User",
            schema: "public");
    }
}
```

As shown, There is only the `TerminationUserId` ForeignKey column, even though the `CreationUser` navigation is set to required.

```cs
    I'm using:
    - Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 2.1.1
    - Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0
    - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 2.0.3
    - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 2.1.1
    - Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools 2.0.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised that the `TerminationUserId` foreign key column was created given that it does not exist in your model. If you want both of these foreign key columns to be created then you need to add them to your model as follows:

```cs
public class AuditedModel : BaseModel
{
    protected AuditedModel(User creationUser)
    {
        CreationUser = creationUser;
        CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    public int CreationUserId { get; protected set; }
    public User CreationUser { get; protected set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; }
    public int? TerminationUserId { get; protected set; }
    public User TerminationUser { get; protected set; }
    public DateTime? TerminationDate { get; }
}
```

And then in your Fluent API mapping:

```cs
    builder.HasOne(u => u.TerminationUser)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey<User>(u => u.TerminationUserId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    builder.HasOne(u => u.CreationUser)
        .WithOne()
        .IsRequired()
        .HasForeignKey<User>(u => u.CreationUserId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Comment: I was trying to have minimum to zero db related code in my model, like a CreationUserId while I already have a CreationUser entity, like in the first 2 MSFT examples in this section: https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/modeling/relationships#fluent-api 

I tried your solution and it works (thank you btw!), but I went further and discovered that it also works if I don't use `.HasForeignKey<User>()` at all. I don't know why I haven't tried it before...

Comment: I didn't realise you were going for the convention approach. Glad you managed to fix it though!